# Unable to install R packages in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package-management, 18.04, shared-library, curl, r

### Issue

Unable to install a few **R packages** (statistical programming language) since updating from 16.04 to **Ubuntu 18.04**.
The problem is related to the use of the shared library `libcurl`. More precisely:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not    
found (required by /home/avila/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl
/libs/curl.so)
```

#### sofar, I tried...

- ... to install a previous version of libcurl with
  `sudo apt-get install libcurl3`, but other libraries were uninstalled on the procedure and R was not usable.

### error output

When trying to install package called "forecast", for example:

```
install.packages("forecast")
 installing to /home/avila/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/forecast/libs
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :  unable to load shared
object '/home/avila/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl/libs/curl.so':
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4: version `CURL_OPENSSL_3' not    
found (required by /home/avila/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl
/libs/curl.so)

ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘forecast’
* removing ‘/home/avila/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/forecast’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘forecast’ had non-zero exit status
```

#### other info:

- R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
- Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that to get predictive results you may want to start with renaming your existing R *personal library* with:

```
mv /home/$USER/R /home/$USER/R_old
```

Also install development package of curl:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

And then try to install your R-package from `R`-terminal:

```
$ R
install.packages("forecast")
```

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked. Please see edited question. 
Should I just slowly reinstall the needed packages or is there a way to find out which package was causing conflicts?
 :)

Comment: The problem was linkage to libcurl from previous Ubuntu version. I do not know the full list of your packages. So consider to  reinstall all of them. If my answer helped, you may accept it.

Answer (score 4):

My resolution came from the Rstudio boards: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-version-curl-openssl-3-not-found/8090

Simply removing the R `curl` package and reinstalling (along with `devtools` etc.) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I fix my problem after run: `install.packages("RCurl")`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me - I also tried re-installing the `curl` package and even reinstalled R.